# Hash functions - show how to find collisions

Tags: computer-science, cryptography

I'm currently trying to solve this exercise (sorry for image, it's for the notation and I'm not allowed yet to post images directly):

[image: http://i.imgur.com/p1b3UY8.png]

I have read the exercise question a lot of times and I think I do understand the most of it.

However, I'm a bit confused about what is meant with the first task "Show that if one can find a...".

I assume that if I can find two messages producing the same hash value, then I got $s_{t+1} = s'_{t'+1}$, and then it would just be to use the same values in the function $f$, which means I would end up with $f(m_{t+1}, s_t) = f(m'_{t'+1}, s'_{t'})$.

Could someone help me by pointing out / give me a hint how I am supposed to show it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed. But $f(m_{t+1}, s_t) = f(m'_{t'+1}, s'_{t'})$ is **only** a collision if the inputs are truely different. So **if** $m_{t+1} \neq m'_{t'+1}$ or $s_t \neq s'_{t'}$, then the inputs are different, and we have a collision in $f$, which we need to show (a collision is two *different* inputs going to the same output). So you still have to handle the case that $m_{t+1} = m'_{t'+1}$ and $s_t = s'_{t'}$.

Now note that $m_{t+1} = m'_{t'+1}$ means that in fact $m$ and $m'$ had the same length (because the last block encodes the original length!). This implies that $t = t'$ as well, because the $t$ (the number of message blocks) is determined directly by the length of the message.

Using that we now know that $s_t = s'_t$ which means $f(m_t, s_{t-1}) = f(m'_t,s'_{t-1})$. Now make the same distinction as before: either a collision in $f$ is found or....

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your answer. To finish your last sentence, it must be "either a collision in f is found or the inputs are the same". But I think I am quite confused. How do I actually use all this to show what the exercise requests?

Comment: The point is, that if you suppose we never have a collision in $f$, we have finitely many steps of equal input instead, and this leads to equal messages, which is a contradiction to the fact that we had a real collision to start with, i.e. some $m_i \neq m'_i$. Let $k$ be the *last* of the indices where $m_i \neq m'_i$...

Comment: So actually you're using a contradiction proof to show that if we can find a collision, then we can easily find a collision for f?

Comment: Yes, Indeed. That's the idea.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Could I ask you what your thoughts are about the last part of the exercise? As I understand, what we can conclude is just that either a collision will happen or the inputs are equal. But I guess that is already covered by what you have told me?